# Relating Gibbs Free Energy to Equilibrium Constants

Tags: thermodynamics

I am having some trouble relating these two concepts. I know that if K=1 then delta g is zero, and that we can interpret signs and magnitudes. However, i am having trouble determining required temparature based on given aimed K, and standart Gibbs free energy of a reaction.
Here is the kind of problem that i have trouble with:[image]

Comment: Have you considered using the Van't Hoff equation?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you did ask anything, you just posted an exercise. What have you tried, and what do you know about how the Gibbs energy or equilibrium constants change with temperature (the two quantities, btw., are temperature-dependent in distinct ways).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this problem, you suppose that $\Delta$$H°$  and $\Delta$$S°$ do not change with temperature. You calculate $\Delta$$G°$ by two approaches : $1)$ - $RT$ ln $K_p$, and $2)$ $\Delta$$H°$ - $T\Delta$$S°$. Then $T$ can be easily obtained.